# Skip a yes/no action within a loop in sending outlook email thru excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

```vba
Sub SendMailWithAttachment()


Dim Result As VbMsgBoxResult

Result = MsgBox("Make sure to change  Account Setting Defaults to .com" & vbNewLine & "Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "EBLAST PRE-PROCEDURE")
If Result = vbNo Then
   Exit Sub

End If

On Error Resume Next

 
 Dim eBlast As Object
 Set eBlast = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 
   
 Dim r As Long
 Dim lastRow As Long
 
     lastRow = Sheets("eBLASTDATA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Dim startRecord As String
     Dim lastRecord As String
     
     startRecord = InputBox(" starting row number:", " BLAST ROW NUMBER START", 3)
        If startRecord = "" Then
           startRecord = 3
        Else
            If startRecord < 3 Then
               startRecord = 3
            End If
        End If
        
     lastRecord = InputBox(" ending row number (not less than 3):", " BLAST ROW NUMBER END", lastRow)
        If lastRecord = "" Then
            lastRecord = lastRow
        Else
            If lastRecord > lastRow Then
               lastRecord = lastRow
            End If
        End If
         
     For r = startRecord To lastRecord
         
         Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
         Set olmail = eBlast.CreateItem(olMailItem)
         
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

         
            With olmail
            
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = ".com"
            .Display
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .To = Sheets("eBLASTDATA").Cells(r, 10).Value
            .CC = Sheets("eBLASTDATA").Cells(r, 11).Value
            .Subject = "Customer Statement as of " & Sheets("eBLASTDATA").Cells(1, 11).Value & " for Customer ID#" & Sheets("eBLASTDATA").Cells(r, 1).Value

            Dim eBlastBody1 As String
            Dim eBlastBody2 As String
            Dim Signature As String
            
         
              
            
            eBlastBody1 = "xxx"               
            eBlastBody2 = ""
            Signature = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" Body").Cells(15, 1).Value
                      
            .HTMLBody = eBlastBody1 & eBlastBody2 & "<img src=" & Chr(34) & Signature & Chr(34) & ">"
            .Attachments.Add Sheets("eBLASTDATA").Cells(r, 12).Value
            


            '.Send
                       
           End With
    On Error Resume Next
   
    Dim TestResult As VbMsgBoxResult
    TestResult = MsgBox("Is this Test  Creation and not to be sent?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "EBLAST PRE-PROCEDURE")
    If TestResult = vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
        Else: olmail.Send
    End If

    
    Next r
       
    Application.EnableEvents = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

    MsgBox "All the mails have been sent !" & vbNewLine & "Don't forget to change your  Account Settings default!"
   
        
 End Sub
```

How do I skip `TestResult` Action and continue the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Test for it not being a Test Email and just send it

```
Dim TestResult As VbMsgBoxResult
TestResult = MsgBox("Is this Test Email Creation and not to be sent?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "EBLAST PRE-PROCEDURE")
If TestResult <> vbYes Then
    olmail.Send
End If
```

Comment: the TestResult msgbox keeps popping. Once the answer is made as No, then it should continue sending emails record range without asking as test email.

Comment: @firesome - try putting that level of detail into your questions in future

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this part:

```vba
 If TestResult = vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
```

What that's doing is, if you answer 'yes' to the messagebox (`TestResult = vbYes`) then it exits the macro altogether.

I'd recommend replacing that whole  block with:

```vba
    Dim TestResult As VbMsgBoxResult
    TestResult = MsgBox("Is this Test  Creation and not to be sent?", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "EBLAST PRE-PROCEDURE")
    If TestResult = vbYes Then 'it's a test
        olmail.display 'display the email and move on.
    Else 'not a test
        olmail.Send 'send the email and move on
    End If
```

Comment: Barnes  if the TestResult is yes if should fully exit because the email creation is already done and can fully review the email sample without sending it. My problem is when the loop is to be continued,  the TestResult Message box keeps popping. How do I avoid it?

Comment: @firesome If that's all it is, why not just move the `Dim Testresult` and `Testresult = msgbox(...` lines to before the `For` loop starts?